# Usar strings.Replace() para reemplazar todos los valores de un diccionario en una cadena

Tags: go

He usado un par de veces esta función y ahora tengo un ejercicio el cual no puedo aun hacer funcionar. Tengo una cadena (`cadena`) y un diccionario (`griegoDicc`), necesito reemplazar cada caracter griego por el valor numérico.
Pero "resultado" es igual a "cadena", no realiza el reemplazo. ¿Alguno sabrá por qué sucede esto?

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    cadena := "ΨφΔξβΨμλΓΛ ΡΘξΡΛξΠμφ λΨξΘΓΠμΓΔ ΨξΛφζΡμλΓ ΔξΛφζΡμλΓ ΔξΛφζΡμλΓ ΔξΨφΔξΡΛξ μηφΔΨξΔΡξ μΨλΓΘξαΓΔ ΡΩΓΘξΣΡΔξ ΡΩξλμΨΩΨξ ΓξΛΓξΩΨζΛ ΡξφΠηΓΛΔΓ ΔξΦΓξΘηξλ μΨΩΨξΔφΠΩ φΘφβΨξΓζμ φΡμΨΩξΛΓΘ ξΞμΨΣφΩαφ ΓΘξηΩφΔΓΘ ξΔΡΛξΘηΔξ ΦξΛΨΘξΛφζ μΡΘξΔΡΛξβ ηΩΔΨξμΡΘΞ ΨΩΔΡΩξΓΛξ ΠμΓΩξΞηΡζ ΛΨξΓμΠΡΩλ φΩΨξΘΓΛηΔ ξΓΛξΠμΓΩξ ΞηΡζΛΨξΓμ ΠΡΩλφΩΨξΘ ΓΛηΔξΦξΛΨ ΘξΛφζμΡΘξ ΔΡΛξβηΩΔΨ ξμΡΘΞΨΩΔΡ ΩξΓΛξΠμΓΩ ξΞηΡζΛΨξΓ μΠΡΩλφΩΨξ ΘΓΛηΔξΦξΛ ΨΘξΛφζμΡΘ ξΔΡΛξβηΩΔ ΨξμΡΘΞΨΩΔ ΡΩξΓΛξΠμΓ ΩξΞηΡζΛΨξ ΓμΠΡΩλφΩΨ ξΘΓΛηΔξαΨ μΨξΘΡΓΩξΡ λΡμΩΨΘξΛΨ ΘξΛΓημΡΛΡ ΘξϑηΡξΘηΞ φβΨΘξαΨΩΘ ΡΠηφμξϑηΡ ξΘηΞφβΨΘξ αΨΩΘΡΠηφμ ξαΨμΨΩΓΔΨ ΘξΔΡξΠΛΨμ φΓξΣφΣΓβΨ ΘξΨξεημΡβ ΨΘξαΨΩξΠΛ ΨμφΓξβΨμφ μξΨξεημΡβ ΨΘξαΨΩξΠΛ ΨμφΓξβΨμφ μξΨξεημΡβ ΨΘξαΨΩξΠΛ ΨμφΓξβΨμφ μ"
    // caracteres := "ΨφΔξβμλΓΛΡΘΠζηαΩΣΦΞϑε "
    var resultado string
    griegoDicc := [][]string{{"Ψ", "700"}, {"φ", "500"}, {"Δ", "4"}, {"ξ", "60"}, {"β", "2"}, {"μ", "40"}, {"λ", "30"}, {"Γ", "3"}, {"Λ", "30"}, {"Ρ", "100"}, {"Θ", "9"}, {"Π", "80"}, {"ζ", "7"}, {"η", "8"}, {"α", "1"}, {"Ω", "800"}, {"Σ", "200"}, {"Φ", "500"}, {"Ξ", "60"}, {"ϑ", "9"}, {"ε", "5"}}

    for _, equivalencia := range griegoDicc {

        resultado = strings.Replace(cadena, equivalencia[0], equivalencia[1], -1)

    }
    log.Print(resultado)

}
```

Comment: Pudiste finalmente decodificar el mensaje? Podrías explicarme? Gracias

Comment: Lamentablemente aun no consigo traducirlo, sospecho que es hexadecimal  en el sistema de numeración griego, pero no he llegado a nada por ese lado ya que hay letras griegas que simbolizan tanto un numero como una letra.

Comment: Consulta pudiste finalmente decodificar el mensaje? Podrías explicarme? Gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En la primera iteración, `resultado` tendrá el reemplazo de `"Ψ"` por `"700"` en `cadena`:

```
resultado = strings.Replace(cadena, "Ψ", "700", -1)
```

En la segunda iteración, `resultado` tendrá el reemplazo de `"φ"` por `"500"` en **`cadena`**:

```
resultado = strings.Replace(cadena, "φ", "500", -1)
```

**¡¿En `cadena`?!**
Ahí está el problema. Siempre estás reemplazando en el string original. En cambio, si le asignaras todo a `resultado` al inicio, y reemplazaras siempre en `resultado` funcionaría:

```
cadena := "ΨφΔξβΨμλΓΛ ΡΘξΡΛξΠμφ λΨξΘΓΠμΓΔ ΨξΛφζΡμλΓ ΔξΛφζΡμλΓ ΔξΛφζΡμλΓ ΔξΨφΔξΡΛξ μηφΔΨξΔΡξ μΨλΓΘξαΓΔ ΡΩΓΘξΣΡΔξ ΡΩξλμΨΩΨξ ΓξΛΓξΩΨζΛ ΡξφΠηΓΛΔΓ ΔξΦΓξΘηξλ μΨΩΨξΔφΠΩ φΘφβΨξΓζμ φΡμΨΩξΛΓΘ ξΞμΨΣφΩαφ ΓΘξηΩφΔΓΘ ξΔΡΛξΘηΔξ ΦξΛΨΘξΛφζ μΡΘξΔΡΛξβ ηΩΔΨξμΡΘΞ ΨΩΔΡΩξΓΛξ ΠμΓΩξΞηΡζ ΛΨξΓμΠΡΩλ φΩΨξΘΓΛηΔ ξΓΛξΠμΓΩξ ΞηΡζΛΨξΓμ ΠΡΩλφΩΨξΘ ΓΛηΔξΦξΛΨ ΘξΛφζμΡΘξ ΔΡΛξβηΩΔΨ ξμΡΘΞΨΩΔΡ ΩξΓΛξΠμΓΩ ξΞηΡζΛΨξΓ μΠΡΩλφΩΨξ ΘΓΛηΔξΦξΛ ΨΘξΛφζμΡΘ ξΔΡΛξβηΩΔ ΨξμΡΘΞΨΩΔ ΡΩξΓΛξΠμΓ ΩξΞηΡζΛΨξ ΓμΠΡΩλφΩΨ ξΘΓΛηΔξαΨ μΨξΘΡΓΩξΡ λΡμΩΨΘξΛΨ ΘξΛΓημΡΛΡ ΘξϑηΡξΘηΞ φβΨΘξαΨΩΘ ΡΠηφμξϑηΡ ξΘηΞφβΨΘξ αΨΩΘΡΠηφμ ξαΨμΨΩΓΔΨ ΘξΔΡξΠΛΨμ φΓξΣφΣΓβΨ ΘξΨξεημΡβ ΨΘξαΨΩξΠΛ ΨμφΓξβΨμφ μξΨξεημΡβ ΨΘξαΨΩξΠΛ ΨμφΓξβΨμφ μξΨξεημΡβ ΨΘξαΨΩξΠΛ ΨμφΓξβΨμφ μ"

var resultado string
griegoDicc := [][]string{{"Ψ", "700"}, {"φ", "500"}, {"Δ", "4"}, {"ξ", "60"}, {"β", "2"}, {"μ", "40"}, {"λ", "30"}, {"Γ", "3"}, {"Λ", "30"}, {"Ρ", "100"}, {"Θ", "9"}, {"Π", "80"}, {"ζ", "7"}, {"η", "8"}, {"α", "1"}, {"Ω", "800"}, {"Σ", "200"}, {"Φ", "500"}, {"Ξ", "60"}, {"ϑ", "9"}, {"ε", "5"}}

//ACÁ asignamos el valor original a resultado
resultado = cadena
for _, equivalencia := range griegoDicc {
    //y acá reemplazamos sobre el valor de resultado
    resultado = strings.Replace(resultado, equivalencia[0], equivalencia[1], -1)
}
log.Print(resultado)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/-TLo-Qga0Di

Comment: OMG! Gracias! No me habia dado cuenta que siempre para reemplazar estoy usando la original.

Answer (score 0):

En realidad el reemplazo de los caracteres del alfabeto griego por los valores numericos de la tabla griega es una de las tantas opciones para la traduccion/decodificacion de mensajes.

Mas bien lo que habria que hacer es algo parecido a lo que se hace con la numeracion romana.
Hay que buscar el patron, ya sea como indice de arreglo, o por interpolacion y tambien por que no por codigo UNICODE (la diferencia del valor de una letra de nuestro alfabeto a uno griego, es un valor constante 848).

Hay varias formas de intentar realizar la interpretacion de ese texto.

Todo esto por que por lo que leo la traduccion de griego de ese texto no es algo coherente si se lo traduce literalmente.

Comment: No entendí la parte de que están a 848 de distancia. El alfabeto griego no sigue el mismo orden que el nuestro, ni tiene la misma cantidad de letras. Por otro lado, entiendo que esta pregunta no busca decodificar un mensaje (si fuese así, probablemente se cerraría), sino de ver el error puntual que el autor estaba teniendo

Comment: Tenes razon, pasa que como no puedo agregar comentarios a los que ya estan escritos escribi una respuesta.

Comment: En los comentarios hablan de que todavia no pudieron decodificar el mensaje y queria comentar sobre la decodificacion. El valor numerico en unicode de cualquier simbolo del alfabeto griego menos el valor numerico 848 te da el correspondiente valor numerico de un caracter de nuestro alfabeto, por ejemplo en valor numerico de la letra ALFA en mayusculas es 915 que menos 848 da 65 que es el valor de nuestra A, y lo mismo el valor numerico de la letra ALFA en minuscula es 945, que menos 848, nos da 97 que es el valor de nuesta "a".

Comment: Pero no deja de ser un minimo comentario en referencia a posibles tecnicas de decodificacion del mensaje. Nada mas. Gracias.